# Authentication url routing with Flask-Login

Tags: flask, flask-restful, flask-login

I am using flask-login for my project.

For my uri, I am using

```
/user/<string:user_id>/
```

when I want to access resources specific to a certain user.

The problem is that, flask-login only provides `@login-required` authentication using cookies. That is, I can only check if the user is logged in or not. Thus, I have to make a separate function to prevent users access urls with different `user_id`.

For example, using only `@login-required` to protect my views allows a user with id `user1` to access `/user/user2`.

How should I make this separate authentication to check if the current user has access to the specific user url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flask-Login` gives you a `current_user` global that you can use to check which user is visiting a certain endpoint and retrieve their `id`. Use it to decide whether a user has access to a certain page.

Your endpoint then becomes

```py
@login_required
@app.route('/user/<string:user_id>')
def user_account(user_id):
    if user_id == current_user.id:
        user = fetch_user_from_storage(user_id)

        return render_template('user_account.html', user=user)
    else:
        flash('You do not have access to this page.')
        # redirect user to another page
```

With this implementation user #1 won't be able to access user #2's data as `current_user.id` will only ever match user #1's `id`.

See the first example in `flask-login`'s [docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example) for more info on `current_user`.

Have a look at [flask-security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) or [flask-principal](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/) if you need more advanced access control.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was my initial solution to the problem, but I read about RESTful url conventions and wanted to follow them. Do you think it is ok to use /user/account in a RESTful point of view?

Comment: I've updated the example to better address your use case. From what I know and understand of REST services/APIs you are correct: every entity needs to have its own URI. In my day-to-day work I tend to approach these things in a RESTful (i.e. lenient REST) manner and would probably use a single URI for all users. :)

Comment: Thanks this really helped!